# Appium - How to keep on Randomly clicking inside a Native Canvas View

Tags: selenium, automation, appium

I am stuck in a step

There is a Native Canvas View in the app that i am automating and i need to click on an element in that view. The issues over here is there is no id or anything to click on that element

So i need to randomly click on different x and y axis inside that view till an element that i want is visible

Comment: Please add example code that represent your current situation.

Comment: Hey....There is no example code as such for now.